# cmder using clink does not show git branch

Tags: git, cmder, clink

When I tick "Use Clink in Cmder" in cmder settings, git branch names are not shown in cmder if I "Open in Terminal" the folder. If I untick it, it is shown, and the output is more colorful, as well.

Is there any benefit to use Clink that cmder does not have?

Comment: If you don't know what are the benefits of using clink in ConEmu, don't turn this option on. Some info is here: https://conemu.github.io/en/TabCompletion.html#ConEmu_and_clink

Comment: After checking again the link you provided, I think clink now is obsolete for me. With Cmder I already have smart history, undo(ctrl+z), copy with ctrl+c, reverse search, etc.. Thanks.

Comment: Surprise, but these features are implemented via clink.

Comment: even when I don't use clink, i.e., with the option unticked?

Comment: It's cmder: a bundle of ConEmu, profile scripts, clink, msysgit and stuff. https://conemu.github.io/en/cmder.html

Comment: Ah.... so I am a little bit confused, so the option actually means "only use console with pure clink without any other extras?"

Comment: As I remember, cmder initialization script loads clink definitely, regardless of ConEmu settings. You may easily check that with [ProcessExplorer](http://conemu.github.io/en/ProcessExplorer.html) for example. Don't you see `Alt-H` clink help?

Comment: OK when I press Alt+H, I see a bunch of commands. I think that is clink help. So the myth is solved, it does uses clink all the time.